# Is there a scala method I can use in if() to check if there is a Null value or not?

Tags: scala, h2o

I tried to write this

```
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._

class Miss extends MRTask{
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
      if(  ){  
       nc.addNum(1)
      }
      else
       nc.addNum(0)
    }
  }
}
```

What can I put in `if (...)` to check whether or not there is a `null` value in that row?

Comment: What is the "that" in "check whether that is a Null"?  Is c index-able?

Comment: What do you want to check for nullity? `row`? Is `row == null` not sufficient. Also don't use `null` ;)

Comment: Yes, I want to check row.

Comment: So why not `row == null`?

Comment: Rather, c[row] == null?

Comment: @isomarcte comparing values of types Int and Null using `==' will always yield false
I got this warning. Should I use isnull or something...I'm not sure about this

Comment: Looking at the water documentation online it looks like c[index] returns a byte value, not a Byte value.  Therefore the warning is correct, you will never get a null when indexing c.

Comment: Can I compare any data type null using row == null?

Comment: @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil Thanks! Let me check!

Comment: @RamonJ.RomeroyVigil I'm very new to this. Forgive me if my question is too basic.. Do you mean by using c[row] I'm indexing c ? Why do I have that warning when I use row == null? Shouldn't the computer compare that row value with null?

Comment: When you do c[row] the return value is a byte (a number).  In Java a byte value can never be null.  So the warning is telling you that checking if a number is null will always return False.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93610/discussion-between-gavin-niu-and-ramon-j-romero-y-vigil).

Comment: @GavinNiu Oh, you are totally correct. That was silly of me. I am not familiar with this library, but `row` can't be `null` because you are explicitly creating a `Range` of `Int` values. It is possible for `c.len()` to return `null` if it is returning something of type `java.lang.Integer`. Is that the case? Can you point me to the API docs?

Comment: @isomarcte http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-dev/rel-serre/1/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/frame.html

Comment: @GavinNiu uh. this is a python api... Are you using Jython or something?

Comment: I'm sorry. Is this what you are looking for? http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-shannon/12/docs-website/h2o-scala/scaladoc/index.html#water.fvec.H2OFrame

Comment: @isomarcte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424324/how-to-add-string-to-new-chunk-in-h2oframe Can you help me take a look at this question? Thanks

Comment: @GavinNiu still confused. There is not `water.fvec.Chunk` defined in the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O provides `Chunk` API which focuses on efficient data processing and internally uses only primitive Java types. Hence, there is no `null` check but you can ask for missing value at given row:

```
if (c.isNA(row)) { ... } else { ... }
```

or shorter version for your example:

```
nc.addNum(c.isNA(row) ? 1 : 0)
```