# How to add string to new chunk in H2Oframe

Tags: scala, h2o

By using `newChunk.addNum(8)` i can add a number to a row in my new chunk. How can I add a String to a row in in the new chunk? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was answered on the H2O google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/nMHmBSMQRRM

Thanks!

Avni

Comment: Thanks for your help!